# $(ab)^m = (ba)^m$ in the center of a group

Tags: group-theory

I need help proving the following statement:

> Let $G$ be a group, $a,b \in G$ such as $(ab)^m \in Z(G)$, where $m$ is a positive integer and $Z(G)$ the center of $G$. Then $(ab)^m = (ba)^m$.

I feel like it should be easy to prove, but I've been at it for a couple hours and I just don't see how to. I've tried proof by contradiction, I've tried to see if $(ba)^m(ab)^{-m} = 1$, but I always end nowhere since $G$ can be a non abelian group. Can someone help? Thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(ab)^m \in Z(G)$, then $(ba)^m = b\underline{(ab)^mb^{-1}} = b\underline{b^{-1}(ab)^m} = (ab)^m$, where I've underlined the expressions where I've used the assumption that $(ab)^m \in Z(G)$, so that it commutes with $b^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\begin{align}
(ab)^ma&=(\underbrace{(ab)\dots(ab)}_{m\text{ times}})a\\
&=a(\underbrace{(ba)\dots(ba)}_{m\text{ times}})\\
&=a(ba)^m
\end{align}$$

by associativity, so $a(ab)^m=(ab)^ma=a(ba)^m$ as $(ab)^m\in Z(G)$, so, cancelling $a$ on the left, we get $(ab)^m=(ba)^m$.